# Test if a node owns a specific child

Tags: xpath

I would like to know if there is a way to check in my xpath if a node owns a specific child
to avoid all others nodes that don't meet the condition.

For instance i have this :

```
/Device/Report
```

And i want to filter, only 'Report' node that owns a node child which name is 'Client', so something like this :

```
/Device/Report::"Client"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have:

```
/Device/Report[Client]
```